# Existence of holomorphic functions which satisfies some inequalities

Tags: complex-analysis

I find an exercice in a book which I am trying to solve: Find all functions f having these properties or show that they do not exist

1. f holomorphic on a neighborhood of $0$ such that for all $n\in\Bbb{N},\quad2^{-n}<\vert f(1/n)\vert<2^{1-n}.$

I get that such a function doesn't exist using the fact that otherwise we have $f(0)=0$ and so $f(z)=z^pg(z)$ with $g(0)\ne 0$ but using the hypothesis I get $g(0)=0$ so such a function doesn't exist.

2. f holomorphic on a neighborhood of $0$ such that for all $n\in\Bbb{N},\quad \vert f(\frac{1}n)-\frac{cos(\pi n)}{2n+1}\vert<\frac{1}{n^2}$

I tried using odd and even numbers, we get first $\vert f(\frac{1}n)-\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}\vert<\frac{1}{n^2}$ and $\vert f(\frac{1}n)+\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}\vert<\frac{1}{n^2}$ but I do not know how to continue.

1. f holomorphic on $U:=\{z\in \Bbb{C}: 1/2<\vert z\vert<1\}$ such that for all $z\in U,\quad f(z)=f(e^{2i\pi \alpha}z)$ where $\alpha$ is irrational.

No idea for this one.

*How can I continue ?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 2., you may write $f(z)=a_0+a_1 z + O(z^2)$ (and use even/odd values of $n$) to run into a contradiction. You may also  show that $f'(0)$ does not exist (it is not a problem of holomorphicity, the function simply can't be differentiable at zero).

For 3. Iterating the condition, noting that $k\alpha\ {\rm mod} \ 1$, $k\in {\Bbb N}$ is dense in $S^1$, you get $f(z) = f( e^{i\phi} z)$ for all $\phi$ (and $z$ in the annulus). You may then conclude.

Comment: thanks, but still,writing $f(z)=a_0+a_1z+O(z^2)$ I get for off values of $n$ that $\vert a_0+\frac{a_1}{2p+1}+O(\frac{1}{(2p+1)^2})+\frac{(-1)^p}{4p+3}\vert<\frac{1}{(2p+1)}^2$(so that $a_0=0$ by taking the limit) and $\vert a_0+\frac{a_1}{2p}+O(\frac{1}{4p^2})+\frac{(-1)^p}{4p+1}\vert<\frac{1}{(4p^2)}^2$, how can I get a contradiction ?

Comment: After eliminating $a_0=0$ you may multiply by $p$ and conclude that this is not possible when $p\rightarrow \infty$

Comment: I get that $\vert a_1\vert 1/2$ for odd and even values of $n.$ I don't see any contradiction, I presume that I miss something ?

Comment: Well, you get that $a_1=1/2$ and $a_1=-1/2$ which is difficult to satisfy simultaneously.

Comment: arf, from the beginning I have $(-1)^n$ after I took odd and even values, that's why I cannot get the result... thanks

Comment: How do you conclude for the 3. ? I don't get the argument

Comment: You may e.g. use that a non-constant holomorphic function has isolated zeroes. If $a\in U$ then  $f(z)-f(a)=f(|z|)-f(|a|)$ vanishes on the circle of radius $|a|$.